# 3D plot with Axes3d does not perform

Tags: python, scipy, pycharm, anaconda

When I try to plot a 3D object in pycharm I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

code structure:

```
# visualizing data with pyplot
#usings
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import urllib
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
#main code
fig=plt.figure()
ax=axes3d(fig)
t=np.linspace(0,5*np.pi,501)
ax.plot(np.cos(t),np.sin(t),t)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

See working code examples  [here](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#wireframe-plots).

I exchanged the line `ax=axes3d(fig)` for `ax=axes3d(fig)` and it ran fine.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
#main code
fig=plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
t=np.linspace(0,5*np.pi,501)
ax.plot(np.cos(t),np.sin(t),t)
plt.show()
```